# Limitations of Visual Studio community version (MAC) for Xamarin projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm new to Xamarin development. Just wanted to know the limitations of using Visual Studio Community version over Professional one.

Also:

1. Is there any restriction or licensing that I need to get while publishing App to PlayStore or AppStore using community version?
2. I have used Xamarin studio earlier (3 months ago), but it is not available for download anymore. Why?

Comment: XS has been replaced by VS for Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is bought by Microsoft and it is becoming a part of the Visual Studio family, so there won't be separate Xamarin products in the future.

Visual Studio Community Edition means that you can use it as long as you work on an open source project or you have up to 5 developers working in your company. There are no other restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Ofcourse you do need to be in the (not free) apple developers program
2. VS for Mac has replaced Xamarin studio

Comment: Yes, I agree there is a licensing for Apple development. But is there any licensing or restriction in VS as well?

Comment: Not that I know of. I have been using it for a long time